# convert unsigned long to char* in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

How do I cast unsigned long to char*.

I am doing the following for loop

```
for (unsigned long i = 1; i< 7;i++)
{
    callAMethod(5,i);
}
```

The method definition is as follows

```
callAMethod(int, const char*)
```

While I do this I get the following error:

```
invalid conversion from `unsigned long' to `const char*'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What makes you think you need to cast it and not just pass a normal `const char *`? This could be an XY problem for all we know.

Comment: I misunderstood what he wants to do.

Comment: As it stands now your problem makes no sense. You might have to either rethink your design or you're doing something inherently wrong.

Comment: Do you want to get the string representation of the long number? Like "5" for i=5?

Comment: You are passing `unsigned long` type to a pointer `const char*`. You might want to read some [C pointers tutorial](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Comment: @e19293001, I don't know if I trust a tutorial that opens by using %d to print a `sizeof` result.

Comment: @chris, What do you mean? Will that produce a security issue or just some bad coding practice?

Comment: @e19293001, The result of `sizeof` is unsigned. %d is for signed integers.

Comment: @chris, Well, you're correct. That's not good!

Comment: You'd cast an unsigned long to `char*` like this:  `char* result = (char*) theUnsignedLong;`.  But of course it would be very stupid to do that.  I suspect what you want to do is *convert* an unsigned long into a character string decimal representation, an entirely different concept.

Comment: @chris - But whatever you're taking the `sizeof` of would have to be pretty enormous for it to make any difference.

Comment: @HotLicks, I prefer things won't unexpectedly stop working when that day comes. Maybe `sizeof` has almost no chance of producing a size that big, but it's still possible with other small things like this to break one day, even if it seems unlikely at first. There's that, and then there's pedantry. It's probably the pedantry.

Comment: @chris - If sizeof gets large enough to go negative in a printf format, it's dangerously close to overflowing entirely.  You have bigger problems than just garbled printing.  (The value of sizeof was made unsigned simply to emphasize that it can never be negative, not to provide one extra bit of coding space.)

Comment: size_t on my system is 64-bit, while int is 32-bit. Here's an easy question: what happens when you push a 64-bit integer on the stack and pop only 32-bit out? What if there are more things to pop after the sizeof() value? Will you pop the next argument, or the other half of the previous value you sliced off?

Answer (score 1):

Old C pointer arithmetic:

```
for (unsigned long i = 1; i< 7;i++)
{
    callAMethod(5, (const char*)(&i));
}
```

But this way you'll just get one byte of the 8 bytes of the long. Do you want to get the string representation of the long? You may utilize STL and get the str().

Answer (score 0):

"const char*" means "address of a character". You're going to pass it values 1 <= n < 7.

You can ask the compiler to pretend they are valid pointer-to-char values by casting

```
callAMethod(5, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(i));
```

But then I'd hazard a guess that your application will crash when it trys to read the memory at address "1" to look for a char

It seems like your "callAMethod" is expecting a C-style string, which is an arbitrary sequence of characters with the end-of-string denoted by a character of value 0:

```
const char hello[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

being equivalent to
    const char* hello = "hello";

(when you write a string in quotes like that in C/C++, the compiler automatically adds a 0 byte to the end of the stored string).

Typically, when you pass strings to a function, the finger print is "const char*"

So what you actually want to know is "how do I make a string from a long value" and the answer is "printf".

```
char str[20];
for (unsigned long i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    sprintf_f(str, "%u", i);
#else
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%u", i);
#endif
    callAMethod(5, str);
}
```