# How do I convert an Unsigned Long into a Char?

Tags: c++, char, integer

I'm currently working on a project for school that will require me to take an unsigned long, `addr` and convert it to a Char. I've tried everything in the books, but I cannot, for the life of me, convert this to a Char and then have it print. Some sample code is posted here:

```
    rw = str[0];
    if (rw == 'r') {
        printf("%s %lx\n", "read", addr);           // Print and test if file is read correctly
   
    }
```

As you can see, in this boiler code, `%lx` is used to indicate that `addr` is an unsigned long. Is there any way someone could give me a snip of code to help turn this into a regular Char? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735965/convert-unsigned-long-to-char-in-c

Comment: Why? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve by this conversion? And when you say "char" do you really mean a single `char`? Do you want it as a characters, or convert the numeric value in `addr` to a byte?

Comment: The sample code isn't helpful without knowing the types of `rw`, `str` and `addr`.  And you should also explain precisely what values each of them have, and what output you are expecting to get.

Comment: It may be possible with the correct algorithm, but in general it's not possible.  A **single** char has only 256 possible values, which is far less than the range for a `long`.  That means that your compression algorithm has only 256 possible combinations to represent all the values in a `long`.  Very difficult.

Comment: The `char` data type can only represent 256 values.  So using a **single char** to represent an address is very unusual; the address would only have 256 (8-bit) locations.  Modern computers have 16-bit to 64-bit address ranges. Long time ago 256 byte of memory was common; in modern times, they are far and few between.

Comment: For multiple `char` values, you should use `std::string`.  For converting a `long` to text, see `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was vague, but I will try to answer it in the way I think you are asking:

**What I think you're asking** : convert an unsigned long to a **char array** :

In that case, you would roughly do the following until the unsigned long (lets call it n) reached 0:

1. Store n modulated by 10 somewhere (lets call it m).
2. If n / 10 == 0, return;
3. Call this function with n/10
4. Put '0' + n into the char array (zero in single quotes; *very important*)

I left some parts out for you to figure out, but this is the direct and most basic approach at the problem.

Comment: What about using `snprintf`?

Comment: I've never heard of snprintf! Sounds useful. I guess that would be better. No point in reinventing the wheel.